# setting frame ids for ekf localization

Tags: slam, navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, encoders

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using wheel encoders and visual odometry(rtabmap) to perform ekf localization. This is the tf tree of rtabmap in localization mode.
map->odom->camera_link(->other camera frames)
I am trying to inculcate my wheel encoders and use ekf for better localization as rtabmap drifts a lot.
How do i set my frames for wheel encoder odometry publisher and broadcaster?
Also, what goes in the base_link_frame in ekf_localization_node param file?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314169/setting-frame-ids-for-ekf-localization/) by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd recommend having a quick look at [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), just so you have a solid understanding of the assumptions about coordinate frames in ROS. With the exception of the *earth* frame, `r_l` conforms to those standards.

In your case, you want the `base_link_frame` to be the coordinate frame that is "affixed" to your robot's origin. All velocities that you generate from your wheel encoder data should be given in this frame. So, if your robot is moving forward at 1.0 meters/sec, the `x` component of velocity in the *base_link* frame will be 1.0, no matter which way your robot is facing.

For your wheel odometry, you need to at least fill out your *base_link* velocity, and set the `child_frame_id` in the `nav_msgs/Odometry` message to be *base_link* (or whatever you want to name your robot's base frame).

*EDIT* in response to comment questions:

> what about the parent frame id of wheel odometry as "odom" is already being used by rtabmap?

That's up to you. Nothing will happen if you also make that frame *odom*, since publishing odometry messages doesn't actually *do* anything to the `tf` tree. Those `frame_id` values just describe what frame the data is in. However, if you make that frame *odom* and then try to fuse the *pose* data from both `rtabmap` and your odometry into the EKF, you definitely will have problems, because, as you stated, they aren't the same frame. But you should just use the velocity data from your odometry anyway. The EKF doesn't like having two sources of pose data, unless they both agree, and they won't.

> also, the camera_link frame is not at the center of the robot. Lets say i publish a static transform from camera_link to base_link, what do i set my wheel odom child frame to be? Sorry. I'm very confused about this.

Wheel odometry child_frame_id should be the `base_link_frame` value, whatever that is. Doesn't matter if there are sensors mounted to your robot. The robot's velocity is relative to its centroid, no matter what's affixed to it.

I'm afraid this particular setup is a bit awkward for `r_l`. First, if `rtabmap` is publishing data into a frame that is relative to `base_link`, that's going to be an issue. All pose data for the EKF needs to either be in the world frame (e.g., *odom*), or needs to have a transform *to* that world frame. The rule basically comes down to this: don't fuse pose data that comes from a `frame_id` that is a child of the `base_link_frame`.

If your camera is not mounted at the origin, you'll actually have to do some extra legwork. I really don't know enough about `rtabmap` to say with certainty what its data looks like. If it were me, I'd do this:

- Set the `rtabmap` `frame_id` for pose data to, e.g., `odom_camera`.
- Set your EKF frames to `odom_frame`: *odom*, `base_link_frame`: *base_link*, `world_frame`: *odom*
- Set your wheel odom frames as `frame_id`: *odom*, `child_frame_id`: *base_link*
- Create a node or modify the `rtabmap` (or even the EKF) source so that you take the actual mounting position of your camera, which we'll call `T_cam`, and rotate it by your current EKF output yaw value: `R_ekf * T_cam`. The result becomes your *odom*->*odom_cam* transform, and you would publish that transform if you did this in an independent node, or just use the transform directly within the code. If you publish the transform, then then the EKF will know how to transform from *odom_cam* to *odom*, and you're golden.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on 2019-01-30**:
what about the parent frame id of wheel odometry as "odom" is already being used by rtabmap?

**Comment by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on 2019-01-30**:
@Tom Moore also, the camera_link frame is not at the center of the robot. Lets say i publish a static transform from camera_link to base_link, what do i set my wheel odom child frame to be? Sorry. I'm very confused about this.

**Comment by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on 2019-01-31**:
Great. I understand it better now. Thank you

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-02-01**:
For `rtabmap`, if `frame_id` parameter of visual odometry (`vo`) is set to `base_link`, the pose computed is already transformed into `base_link` frame, i.e., the odom topic published by `vo` will really mean `odom` -> `base_link`. Set also `publish_tf` for `vo` to false to avoid TF conflicts.